# How do I set the text on a Button in Android, from a thread?

Tags: android, button

In my main layout XML I have:

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02">

<Chronometer android:text="@+id/Chronometer01" android:id="@+id/Chronometer01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Chronometer>


<Button android:text="@string/hints" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button01"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
<com.touchpanel.Panel android:id="@+id/SurfaceView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.touchpanel.Panel>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my Panel class, I spawn a thread to do the drawing for itself. My question is, can I access the Button in the other linear layout to change the text? (This would happen quite a bit, the text is dynamic)

I tried declaring the button in the activity using this layout, but I can't access it from the Panel class. I can write a function that takes the text as a parameter to put to the button, but if I call it from the Panel class it force closes. If I comment out the "button1.setText("Text");" line, it handles the function call fine.

Trying to declare the button in the Panel class, such as:

```
private Button b1; //Declared at the beginning of the class

//in constructor of Panel class:
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
b1.setText("Hello");
```

It declares the button, and sets it fine. But when I try to use the line "b1.setText" it force closes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to ask this question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/   It is a StackExchange community, like StackOverflow, dedicated to Android questions.

Comment: @Josh: Development questions are [explicitly off-topic](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq) on Android SE. They should be posted here, as the OP has done. Android SE is for **users** of Android devices, not developers.

Comment: If it is force closing, could you provide a stack trace from logcat?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify the UI from a non-UI thread. Use a `Handler`. Or, call `post()` on your `Button`. Or, use `runOnUiThread()`. Or, dump the thread and use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: "You cannot modify the UI from a non-UI thread" Figured. I was hoping it wasnt true since it would be a lot easier. Thanks